# console says flatMap() isnt a function even though it is

Tags: javascript, bots, discord, discord.js

I'm coding a bot with 3 people and there is a random error i can't fix which is super annoying, I keep getting the error 'flatMap() isn't a function' 
Code:

```js
module.exports = () =>
  getFilenames('../widgets')
    .map(getHandlerFilePath)
    .flatMap(getHandlers)
    .reduce(groupByHandlerName, { ready: [] });
```

Comment: you should confirm whether `.map(getHandlerFilePath)` is returning array or not, that happens when `flatMap` is not being called on array.

Comment: Sounds like your node version doesn't support flatMap, consider upgrading